# European Encoding

Tags: java, xml, encoding

I am a bit struggling with encodings lately. We have an inhouse program that sends journals from database to message queue in XML format. The problem is that DB server for multiple countries across the Europe including **Greece, Spain, France, Sweden, Poland, Czech ETC**. I need to set a correct encoding so all characters in all European countries are encoded and not substituted by 0x1a. There are many encodings available, but which one is correct for all European countries?

When a character gets substituted further java parsing throws an exception. I have used **UTF-8 and ISO-8895-7**, but each does substitution for some characters.

Comment: I don’t know what “I have used UTF-8” actually means.  Normally, when writing XML, you don’t set an encoding, which causes the resulting XML document to use UTF-8, which can properly represent every single Unicode character.  Consider editing your question and showing us the code that makes use of an encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the systems from which you collect your jounals use different encodings.

Unfortunately there is no magic encoding you can use to display all encodings correctly.

I see two options:

1. Send the journals and the used encoding, so that you can use the correct encoding for each journal to display.
2. Convert all journals from the system/db-encoding to UTF-8 and send them in UTF-8.

Comment: This seem to be the correct way in the end. Thanks for suggestion